# easy code not working on empty project ( binding ,input , ng model) in any browser

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Im having a problem with the following code, is a simple one, i want to be able to se in my view what i put in the input text. but nothing is happening. when running in the online simulator no problem, but in my browser nothing happens. what im doing wrong?. my project is empty. Also tried it in firefox, explorer and chrome, and not working at all. the only thing i have is this pice of code. have no error in browser console... im using angular cli.
what im doing wrong guys? please help.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
    $scope.lastname = "Doe";    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input ng-model="firstname">
    <h1>{{firstname}}</h1>
</div>
```

[SOURCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWTtS.jpg)

Comment: The `src` should be inside your `script` tag.

Comment: still not working.

Comment: Here's the exact copy of your code and it works fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/RNCJlAIvSQHKwI5mPyea?p=preview

Comment: @IxamDeirf your code works fine, i put inside script tag. you can check it

Comment: @PrerakSola  yeah thats the strange thing.... in every simulator it works...but not when i program it .. the code is form here 

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_databinding_two-way

Comment: There should be some error in your browser console.

Comment: @IxamDeirf provide your written code snapshot and console

Comment: @PrerakSola no errors there.... im burning my head with this. it is so simple and i cant make it work.

Comment: @NileshKhisadiya there u have some links with the code. console show 0 errors.

Comment: Post the screenshot of your browser window along with its console.

Comment: @PrerakSola THERE U HAVE A LINK WITH THE SCREENSHOOT.

Answer (score 1):

In the example that you are referring as well as in the code that you posted above, you have:

```
$scope.firstname = "John";
$scope.lastname = "Doe";
```

But in screenshot of your `script.js` you have:

```
$scope.data = {
    firstname : "John";
    lastname: "Doe";
};
```

Both of these are different. The valid HTML attribute with each of these will be:

**Method One: Works with code posted above**

```
Name: <input ng-model="firstname">
<h1>{{firstname}}</h1>
```

**Method Two: Works with the script.js as per your screenshot**

```
Name: <input ng-model="data.firstname">
<h1>{{data.firstname}}</h1>
```

So use either one of them as per your JS code.

Comment: yes your right...tried it again , but nothing happens :(

Comment: Update the question with the exact code that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script >
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
    $scope.lastname = "Doe";    
});
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input ng-model="firstname">
    <h1>{{firstname}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @IxamDeirf may be you missed something in your demo proj

Comment: something like what? i can see the input box... but is now working properly.

Comment: @IxamDeirf like script path, syntactical or browser caching related issue. but somehow we did not identify such issue.

Comment: i found out something... in my app folder the ts files are recognized as mpeg-2 TS video... is that affecting me in some way? or i have to ignore that?

Comment: i do not think this will affect it. please check your code file render or not using the source tab in browser

Comment: could you please create demo proj in simple folder structure, like add app folder, inside one html page and script file with above same code. I had created it and works fine.

Comment: Yes i did, all the code in one html page... bit still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is second time, you posted same question. The potential reason for not working your code inside browser may be you are not adding the your `script.js` path correctly. Check your browser console and debug the issue. Your code seems fine.

Just copy and paste this code inside a `.html` file and open in browser. It should work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
    $scope.lastname = "Doe";    
});

</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input ng-model="firstname">
    <h1>{{firstname}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: it is beacuase i can not make it work properly... i tried doing it everything in html but have no effect as well. i just added some pictures of my code.

Comment: @IxamDeirf can you share the screenshot of your browser console.

Comment: there u have  link with screenshoot.

Comment: :( i started the project like this...

ng new prueba

then inside prueba folder installed npm install

then ng serve... after that i added the example code..serve it againg,  but nothing happens.